# Why cant i use my projection field in my switch case?

Tags: database, mongodb, switch-statement, pipeline, aggregation

Im trying to apply a timezone field called 'summary' to my documents by doing a case against the month, why cant I use the 'month' projection field in my switch cases?

```
 db.steps.aggregate( [
      {
        $project:
          {
            patientName : 1,
            month: {$month: '$dateTime'},
            hour: {$hour: '$dateTime'},
            minute: {$minute: '$dateTime'},
            day: {$dayOfMonth: '$dateTime'},
            "summary" :
            {
              $switch:
                {
                  branches: [
                    {
                      case: { $eq : [ '$month', 6 ] },
                      then: "month 6"
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq : [ '$month', 7 ] },
                      then: "month 7"
                    }
                  ],
                  default: "No value found."
                }
             }
          }
       },
       { $group: { _id: {"day":"$day", "month":"$month", "summary":"$summary"}}}
    ]);
```

Instead of getting the correct thens it just goes to the default:

```
{ "_id" : { "day" : 24, "month" : 9, "summary" : "No value found." } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 29, "month" : 9, "summary" : "No value found." } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 22, "month" : 6, "summary" : "No value found." } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 19, "month" : 7, "summary" : "No value found." } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 6, "month" : 8, "summary" : "No value found." } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 2, "month" : 9, "summary" : "No value found." } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 24, "month" : 7, "summary" : "No value found." } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 6, "month" : 9, "summary" : "No value found." } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 31, "month" : 7, "summary" : "No value found." } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 10, "month" : 9, "summary" : "No value found." } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 12, "month" : 9, "summary" : "No value found." } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 22, "month" : 9, "summary" : "No value found." } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 13, "month" : 9, "summary" : "No value found." } }
```

can you not use the a projection field in the same stage?

Thanks

Comment: you can access projection field in next stage, but not in same stage, just use `{$month: '$dateTime'}` instead of `$month`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to field within the same stage. Here are two possible solutions:

```
db.steps.aggregate( [
      {
        $project:
          {
            patientName : 1,
            month: {$month: '$dateTime'},
            hour: {$hour: '$dateTime'},
            minute: {$minute: '$dateTime'},
            day: {$dayOfMonth: '$dateTime'},
            "summary" :
            {
              $switch:
                {
                  branches: [
                    {
                      case: { $eq : [ {$month: '$dateTime'}, 6 ] },
                      then: "month 6"
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq : [ {$month: '$dateTime'}, 7 ] },
                      then: "month 7"
                    }
                  ],
                  default: "No value found."
                }
             }
          }
       },
       { $group: { _id: {"day":"$day", "month":"$month", "summary":"$summary"}}}
    ]);



db.steps.aggregate( [
      {
        $project:
          {
            patientName : 1,
            month: {$month: '$dateTime'},
            hour: {$hour: '$dateTime'},
            minute: {$minute: '$dateTime'},
            day: {$dayOfMonth: '$dateTime'}
          }
       },
      {
        $set: // $project would remove all others
          {
            "summary" :
            {
              $switch:
                {
                  branches: [
                    {
                      case: { $eq : [ '$month', 6 ] },
                      then: "month 6"
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq : [ '$month', 7 ] },
                      then: "month 7"
                    }
                  ],
                  default: "No value found."
                }
             }
          }
       },
       { $group: { _id: {"day":"$day", "month":"$month", "summary":"$summary"}}}
    ]);
```

NB, I would prefer

```
{ $cond: 
   { 
      if: {$in: ['$month', [6,7]]}, 
      then: { $concat: [ "month ", '$month' ] }, 
      else: "No value found."
   } 
}
```

Comment: ah yes i think I tried reading it from dateTime exactly, but i wasn't using the correct syntax. Thank you!